# Want to display advertise in footer of react-native application

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

is it possible to display advertise in the footer in react native application??

```
    <AdMobBanner style={{ position: 'absolute',bottom:0}}
        adSize = "mediumRectangle"
        adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"
        onAdFailedToLoad={error => console.error(error)}
      />
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You can use some libraries such as [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and [react-native-admob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob) to show google admobs in react native.